# xslt grouping by calling template

Tags: templates, xslt, grouping, xslt-grouping

I am new to xslt and trying to learn how to learn grouping using keys and using templates.

Can somebody help me on how can do the following in xslt.
I have to call a template from another template to do the transformation.

Thanks

here is my xml.

```
<Doc>
<ExOrder>121</ExOrder>
<Line>
    <Ordernumber>225</Ordernumber>
    <OrderID>1</OrderID>
    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
</Line>
<Line>
    <Ordernumber>225</Ordernumber>
    <OrderID>5</OrderID>
    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
</Line>
<Line>
    <Ordernumber>226</Ordernumber>
    <OrderID>2</OrderID>
    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
</Line>
```

And here is how it should look like after.

```
<Doc>
    <Order>
        <Ordernumber>225</Ordernumber>
        <Line>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <ID>5</ID>
        </Line>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <Ordernumber>225</Ordernumber>
        <Line>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <ID>5</ID>
        </Line>
    </Order>
</Doc>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume the output you actually want is:

```
<Doc>
  <Order>
    <Ordernumber>225</Ordernumber>
    <Line>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <ID>5</ID>
    </Line>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <Ordernumber>226</Ordernumber>
    <Line>
      <ID>2</ID>
    </Line>
  </Order>
</Doc>
```

Since the sample output you provided makes no sense.  This XSLT will produce the output above when run on your sample input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kOrder" match="Line" use="Ordernumber"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <Doc>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Line[generate-id() = 
                                        generate-id(key('kOrder', Ordernumber)[1])]" />
    </Doc>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Line">
    <Order>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Ordernumber" />
      <Line>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kOrder', Ordernumber)/OrderID" />
      </Line>
    </Order>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="OrderID">
    <ID>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </ID>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes your are right. sorry about the misleading output. Thanks for your reply.  I will try your solution and let you know.